# Неправильная работа скрипта

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, redirect

Есть такая конструкция:
На каждой странице сайта (в футере) есть код

```
<button style="display:none!important" id="block1">
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("timeraSZ") === "true") {} else {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.get('/shop/invoices', function(data) {
        $('#block1').html($('.col_inv_id', data).html());
        setTimeout(function() {
          var link = $('#block1 a').attr('href');
          window.location.replace(link);
        }, 100);
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Он со страницы `/shop/invoices` подгружает первый элемент с нужным классом и выводит его в `button id="block1"`, и после загрузки страницы происходит редирект по ссылке указанной в  подгружаемом блоке.Также это все заключено в проверку `sessionStorage`.
Пример подгружаемого блока:

```
<a href="/shop/order/UqSUWOw423YzfeP9yt0DAU5hg9ZnvUdNI6MVPsko" title="Просмотр заказа">00018</a><small><a href="javascript://" onclick="return invoiceJournal('18')">журнал</a></small>
```

а также вторая ссылка скрыта

```
 <style>#block small a {pointer-events: none;cursor: default;display:none}</style>
```

На странице, на которую просходит редирект установлен код

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    setTimeout(function(){history.back();}, 100);
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    sessionStorage.setItem("timeraSZ", "true");
</script>
```

Первое - возврат на предыдущую страницу, второе - создание той самой записи в `sessionStorage`.Но тут появились 2 проблемы:

1. Первый скрипт срабатывает через раз.То есть, даже если записи нет,
   то все равно скрипт не срабатывает.Через 5-6 перезагрузок может
   сработать.
2. Самое главное, `history.back()` возвращает не на ту страницу с
   которой пришел, а на страницу перед ней.

То есть - если я был на `/shop`, очистил хранилище и перешел на `/shop/dal/01`, то после выполения скриптом меня возвращает не на `/shop/dal/01`, а на  `/shop`. Все бы ничего, но при попытке входа на сайт с адресной строки напрямую - невозможно, ибо если я захожу на тот же `/shop`, меня возвращает на домашнюю страницу / поисковик. то есть, возвращает на 2 шага назад, вместо одного. Я пробовал и просто `history.back()`, и `history.back(-1)`, и `history.go(-1)` и т.д - одинаково.

Comment: P.S.Первый вопрос - не так сильно важен, а вот второй - "катастрофа"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вопрос решился просто - кусок `if (sessionStorage.getItem("timeraSZ") === "true") { }` надо было заменить на

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("timeraSZ") === "true") { 
}
```

Второй решился заменой `window.location.replace(link);` на `$(location).attr('href',link);`

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на второй вопрос. Цитата с ресурса [MDN Location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace).

> The Location.replace() method replaces the current resource with the
>   one at the provided URL. The difference from the assign() method is
>   that **after using replace() the current page will not be saved in
>   session History**, meaning the user won't be able to use the back
>   button to navigate to it.

Comment: То есть браузер не запоминает ее посещение?Как это можно исправить/заменить?

Comment: Судя по всему необходимо использовать метод [Location.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location/assign)

Comment: везде  Location.replace() заменить на  Location.assign() ?